# Display foreign key data in parent model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have 2 model:

```
class Sideshow_manager(models.Model):
    url_id              = models.CharField(max_length=250,editable=False,unique=True)
    title               = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date                = models.DateField()
    image               = models.ImageField(upload_to='slideshow',verbose_name='400*400px')
    image_title         = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image_alt           = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    page_title          = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    page_description    = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Slideshow_image_manager(models.Model):
    url_id              = models.CharField(max_length=250,editable=False,unique=True)
    parent              = models.ForeignKey(Sideshow_manager)
    image               = models.ImageField(upload_to='slideshow',verbose_name='400*400px')
    image_title         = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image_alt           = models.CharField(max_length=100)    
    page_title          = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    page_description    = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Can I let Django admin display all record of Slideshow_image_manager when I go to an item of Sideshow_manager that Slideshow_image_manager adopt to parent instead of display that 2 list separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inlines, ie.

```
class SlideshowImageManagerInline(admin.TabularInline):
  model=Slideshow_image_manager
  ...

class SideshowManagerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlindes=[SlideshowImageManagerInline]
  ...

admin.site.register(Sideshow_manager, SideshowManagerAdmin)
```

Docs are [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)